# Spring Exception Handler being called properly but what is returned is not the same

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a custom ControllerExceptionHandler that handles a specific Exception, call it MyAppException, that I created for my application. Pretty much anywhere in my services I throw this MyAppException that is a wrapper for the actual exception that was thrown. This works really well and exactly how I want it to except for a specific case.

I use Spring WebClient to make a call to another application. I pause this other application (using docker pause) to simulate the service not being available. The WebClient expectedly throws a WebClientRequestException which I catch. I then create a MyAppException to wrap another specific Exception indicating that this specific application is down. My ControllerExceptionHandler method for MyAppException is properly called which logs the exception and then returns a new ResponseEntity with an appropriate message and an HTTP Status of 500. But what I see in the actual return is a 504 HTTP Status and a message indicating there was a timeout. My customer ResponseEntity is never returned. It seems like it is being intercepted or overridden somehow.

Anybody have any clues?

Comment: Maybe provide a bit more context about your application and server, and a bit more clarity about the parties in the exchange. How many clients and servers are we talking about? Where do you see the 500 and the 504?

Comment: My server, which is a Spring Boot Web App running in Docker, is attempting to call another Spring Boot Web App running in a different Docker container. I am initiating the call using Swagger to my App as part of testing. A 504 is being returned from my Server which I see in the Response body in Swagger. I am expecting a 500 with a specific message because that is how the Exception Handler is coded. In the logs of my server I see that the proper method is called and the 500 expected is returned from that method.

Comment: Does the 504 return before the 500 is generated, perhaps? Where your Swagger client is timing out, because of your docker pause, before the code is able to return the 500?